# Magento - Free Shipping Message

Tags: magento

How can I make appear a free shipping message in product list and product page and cart?

The message should appear in the product list and product page only if the price of the product is bigger than $50, and in the cart if the total is bigger than $50.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

you can download this extension [free-shipping-incentive](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/creare-free-shipping-incentive.html) and modify/upgrade/edit etc it, change it the way you want it to be.

Get the idea from:

1. [here](http://www.immense.net/magento-free-shipping-certain-products/)
2. [here](http://www.ankitsharma.info/blog/magento-free-shipping-on-specific-category-product)
3. [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/40357/)

Comment: Hi, but with this codes every time that I create a new product I'll have to set if the current product have a free shipping, right? Because I want one code that works this way, "if the current product price is bigger than $50, appears Free Shipping", because I want to change this price for a smaller later, and I will not be able to change one by one all again.

Comment: hi, do not jump ahead, just read everything, buy the way you can google all these. cheers

Answer (score 3):

**Hi Marcelo**,
To display free shipping message on product details page : `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
$productprice = echo $_product->getPrice();
if($productprice >= 50)
{
echo 'free shipping is available for this product if cart total is greater than $50';
}
```

To display on product listing page to have add photo tagging above product image "Free shipping". path : `template/catalog/category/view.phtml`add condition similar as above 
To avail free shipping for cart taotal greater than $ 50 :
Go to admin :

```
System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods
```

**Enabled** : Yes
**Minimum cart Total** : 50
Hope This helps you . . .

Comment: In another forum one guy helped me, if someone needs is just ask that I post here

Answer (score 0):

Have used the above successfully and added a second message to encourage people to buy up to £50.00 for free shipping

```
        <?php if ($_product->getSpecialPrice() > 50.00):
        echo $this->__('With Free UK Shipping');
        endif; ?>

        <?php if ($_product->getSpecialPrice() < 50.00) :
        echo $this->__('Spend £50.00 To Get Free UK Shipping');
        endif; ?>
```

Problem is these message are based only on the SpecialPrice  but i need it to show the message based on Price (RRP) if SpecialPrice is null or 0
Not a great coder but could do with some help
Would also like to have statement showing how much more needs to be purchased before free shipping